# Разность произведения и суммы квадратов всех элементов

Tags: c++, массивы

Задание таково:**В массиве вещественных чисел  Z=(z1,z2,…,zм) определить 
разность произведения и суммы квадратов всех элементов**

Выдает ошибку на 18 и 22 строке:

> Ошибка (активно)  E2140   выражение должно относиться к целочисленному типу или типу перечисления без области видимости

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, int endl, int cout, char* argv[])
{
FILE *inp_stream, *out_stream;
float inp_data, total_mul = 1, total_square = 1;

inp_stream = fopen("c:/c++/input.txt", "r");
out_stream = fopen("c:/c++/output.txt", "w");

while ((fscanf(inp_stream, "%f", &inp_data)) != EOF)
{
    total_mul *= inp_data;
    total_square += (inp_data*inp_data);
    cout << inp_data << endl;
}
cout << endl;
total_mul -= total_square;
cout << total_mul << endl;
fprintf(out_stream, "%f", total_mul);
fclose(inp_stream);
fclose(out_stream);

return 0;
}
```

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пункт первый - что за...?

```
int main(int argc, int endl, int cout, char* argv[])
```

Какие такие `int endl, int cout`??? Для `cout <<` нужно

```
#include <iostream>
```

и

```
using namespace std;
```

не помешает.

И тогда все скомпилируется. Но работать все равно будет неверно - хотя бы почему у вас начальное значение `total_square` равно 1?

А вообще, смесь "французского с нижегородским" - читай C и C++ - выглядит очень некрасиво...